# cocoa custom view fading in/out new image when dragging

Tags: image, cocoa, view, fade

I have a custom view that accepts drags.  In the custom view there is an image and the words Drag items here.  I would like to make it where when dragging an item over the view the image will fade into another image, then when dragging away it will fade back to the original image.  Also, when it will fade into the new image I will make the words Drag items here fade away, then fade back again when dragging away.  I think I can do this with another view but I want to keep the original view so that it will continue to accept drags.  What is the right approach to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Apple demo [ImageTransition](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ImageTransition/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010277-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2), it does what you want, at least for image